# GWT Celltable fixed columns

Tags: java, gwt

Is there a way to make, let say first 3 out of 7, columns fixed in Cell table. I want to be able to see always first three columns and have horizontal scroll on others.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a custom widget that consists of a ScrollPanel, which includes two CellTable widgets set side by side. The right table should be wrapped in a FlowPanel with overflow-x property set to AUTO (overflow-y should remain at HIDDEN).

You can use the same DataProvider for both tables to synchronize all changes. Be careful with the SelectionModel though, if you need it. I would limit selection to the first column of checkboxes and disable selection by clicking on a row.

Make sure that your widget fits into its space, or you may end up with two horizontal scrollbars - one for the ScrollPanel and one for the right table. Finally, remember to set sizes on both tables so that they have the same height.